# Using local average color of image to reduce difference in lightning

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to opencv and I am currently working on 'Diabetic Retinopathy Detection' (a kaggle competition was launched 3 years ago; more details here : https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/data). Currently, I am trying to achieve similar results on image processing as depicted in the image below (source: http://blog.kaggle.com/2015/09/09/diabetic-retinopathy-winners-interview-1st-place-ben-graham/):
[image]

Now I have tried different approaches including histogram equalization and Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization (CLAHE). CLAHE gives the best results so far, but nothing compared to the images above. I got some ideas from here : ([How to remove the local average color from an image with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437181/how-to-remove-the-local-average-color-from-an-image-with-opencv)) but couldn't reproduce the results. If someone can guide me how it can be done with opencv or any other python vision library, it would be great. Sample images can be downloaded from kaggle site (link mentioned above). Thanks.

Here is my code so far:

```
def equalize_hist(input_path):
    img = cv.imread(input_path)
    for c in range(0, 2):
        img[:,:,c] = cv.equalizeHist(img[:,:,c])

    cv.imshow('Histogram equalized', img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

def clahe_rgb(input_path):
    bgr = cv.imread(input_path)
    lab = cv.cvtColor(bgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    lab_planes = cv.split(lab)
    gridsize = 5
    clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0,tileGridSize=(gridsize,gridsize))
    lab_planes[0] = clahe.apply(lab_planes[0])
    lab = cv.merge(lab_planes)
    bgr2 = cv.cvtColor(lab, cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    cv.imshow('CLAHE RGB', bgr2)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()


def clahe_greyscale(input_path):
    img = cv.imread(input_path)
    gray_image = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    cl1 = clahe.apply(gray_image)    
    cv.imshow('CLAHE Grayscale', cl1)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You should edit your code into the question.

Comment: Hi. I have posted my code above.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show is doing a local histogram equalization, whereas the highlighted text you posted talks about removing the average color from each pixel.

Removing the average color could be done like this:

```
# Blur the image
blurred = cv2.blur(img, ksize=(15, 15))

# Take the difference with the original image
# Weight with a factor of 4x to increase contrast
dst = cv2.addWeighted(img, 4, blurred, -4, 128)
```

You can adjust the kernel size of the blur code (above it's 15) to find something that works for your use case.

You may need to downscale the images to a common size before doing this, to get comparable results (as also noted in the blog post you cite).

Comment: It gives me an image with dark grey shade all over it. Were you able to get similar output as I posted above ?

Comment: I don't have the original kaggle data. Did you try downsizing the image or increasing the kernel size?

Comment: Hi. yes I have. With increasing kernel size, the lines become sharp, but CLAHE results are even better than that. For testing, you can download one image from the 'sample.zip' of kaggle link I pasted above (it's ~10 Mb of data I think).

Comment: I've had another look at the blog post. It shows excerpts from a technical report that can also be found online: https://www.kaggle.com/blobs/download/forum-message-attachment-files/2795/competitionreport.pdf - on page 6 you get the Python source code.

Comment: The code there increases the contrast by using a weighted difference (with a factor of 4). I've updated the code in the answer to do the same.

Comment: The code seems the same to me (may be you forgot to updated ?). I am trying to implement that pseudo code, but running into some memory errors, don't know why.